# Removing an object from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to remove the object at index 1 but the code won't compile.

I also don't understand this: I set "iphone" string to the index 0, after that I remove it from index 0 but the output still displays "iphone" on first. Can anyone can explain it to me?

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{    
    @autoreleasepool {

        //create three string objetc
        NSString *banana  = @"This is banana";
        NSString *apple = @"This is apple";
        NSString *iphone =@"This is iPhone";

        //create  an empty array
        NSMutableArray *itemList = [NSMutableArray array];

        // add the item to the array
        [itemList addObject:banana];
        [itemList addObject:apple];

        // put the iphone to the at first

        [itemList insertObject:iphone atIndex:0];

        for (NSString *l in itemList) {
            NSLog(@"The  Item in the list is %@",l);
        }
        [itemList removeObject:0];
        [itemList removeObject:1];// this is not allow  it

        NSLog(@"now the first item in the list is %@",[itemList objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"now the second time in the list is %@",[itemList objectAtIndex:1]);
        NSLog(@"now the thrid item in the list is %@",[itemList objectAtIndex:2]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be

```
[itemList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[itemList removeObjectAtIndex:1];
```

This method is clearly stated in the documentation for `NSMutableArray`. Please always consult the proper documentation before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

The method `removeObject:(id)obj` doesn't work with indices but with actual objects.

You should use instead

```
[list removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[list removeObjectAtIndex:1];
```

If you wonder why it works with `0`, I guess because `0 == NULL == nil` which is a pointer to a null object, so it's interpreted as the nil object instead that an index (it won't behave like you'd expect).

Answer (score 2):

You are using removeObject instead of removeObjectAtIndex.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
[itemList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

[Here's a detailed guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `NSMutableArray`.